# Django Form Wizard persistent initial data between steps

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I'm using [Django Form Wizard](https://django-formwizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in project. I want to allow users to provide initial data for specific field and I also want to make field with initial data provided disabled.

> Problem is that when user clicks back button the initial data is erased.

For example this is my form(initial data is set as second step)
[image]
As you can see everything is fine here, the form fields are disabled and the value is selected. Now we click `next`.

[image]
We click `next` and we get to the second step without problems but now if I click `back`..
[image]

Form fields are still disabled but the value is gone!

The code I'm using goes like this (relevant part):
**Form**

```
CHOICES=[('ONE','Choice 1'),
         ('TWO','Choice 2'),
         ('THREE','Choice 3'),
         ('FOUR','Choice 4'),
        ]

class BookingForm1(forms.Form):
    """ Select reservation type"""
    sko = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

**Wizard**

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(PresentView, self).get_form(step, data, files)
        step = step or self.steps.current

        initial = {
            'sko': {
                'initial':'TWO'
            }
        }

        for field in initial:
            try:
                form.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
                form.fields[field].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
                form.fields[field].required = False
                form.fields[field].initial = initial[field]['initial']
            except:
                pass
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't have a fix for you, but here's an explanation of why it's not working: When you disable the field, that means that the browser does not submit the value to the server. When you go back to the original form, the form is bound, so Django used the form data and ignores the `initial` data. However the form data does not contain a value for the disabled field, so no value is selected when the form is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The way I was able to solve it was by removing extra fields for `ChoiceField` type objects.

```
 for field in initial:
            try:
                field_o = form.fields[field]
                # Remove extra choices if Choice field
                if type(field_o) == forms.fields.ChoiceField:
                    field_o.choices = [(key, value) for key,value in field_o.choices if key == initial[field]['initial']]
                else:
                    field_o.widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

                field_o.initial = initial[field]['initial']
            except:
                pass
```